# Backbone.js Why is my default model present in a fetched collection?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I'm sure I'm missing something very basic. I'm setting up a collection of fetched objects

`collection.fetch({reset: true})`

based on a model that contains a 'defaults' property.

However, when I view the fetched collection in the console I have an extra model in it, which is set with the default attributes. Why is this happening? More importantly, how do I prevent it?

```
var diningApp = diningApp || {};

(function(){
"use strict";

diningApp.MenuItem = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        service_unit: null,
        course: null,
        formal_name: null,
        meal: null,
        portion_size: null,
        service_unit_id: null
    }
});

var MenuCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: diningApp.MenuItem,

    url: '/api/dining/get_menus',

    parse: function(response){
        return response.menu_items;
    }
});

diningApp.menuCollection = new MenuCollection();
diningApp.menuCollection.fetch({reset: true});
})();
```

Here is a portion of the JSON response from the server:

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "menu_items": [
  {
    "service_unit": "Faculty House",
    "course": "Entrees",
    "formal_name": "Local CF Fried Eggs GF",
    "meal": "BREAKFAST",
    "portion_size": "1 Egg",
    "service_unit_id": 0
  },
  {
    "service_unit": "Faculty House",
    "course": "Entrees",
    "formal_name": "CageFree Scrambled Eggs GF",
    "meal": "BREAKFAST",
    "portion_size": "2 eggs",
    "service_unit_id": 0
  }]
}
```

And here's the resulting collection in the console:

[image]

Comment: What does the JSON from `/api/dining/get_menus` look like?

Comment: Edited to include JSON response.

Comment: @lancemonotone It seems to work with the sample data you gave http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/cjd7syoh/ An undefined/empty/null element somewhere in the full JSON? http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/cjd7syoh/1/

Comment: What happens, if you comment one of your `default`s? It's still apper in a ghost model? Seems like a broken response for me

Comment: @nikoshr, A 'false' element in my JSON response was indeed the culprit. That's certainly a weird behavior. Is there any reason for it? If you would like to answer the question, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dig a bit into Backone's source code to check what happens when you reset a collection, you'll end looking at [`Collection.set`](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-89). The lines of interest to your problem are :

```
// Turn bare objects into model references, 
// and prevent invalid models from being added.
for (i = 0, l = models.length; i < l; i++) {
    attrs = models[i] || {};
    // ...
```

This means that each falsy (false, null, etc.) item in the array is converted to an empty object before being cast into a model and receiving default values.

Either

- modify your server response to remove falsy values
- or alter your `parse` method to clean up you array

  ```
  parse: function(response){
      return _.compact(response.menu_items);
  }
  ```

Comment: _.compact is a nice solution. I feel like this behavior in Backbone should be advertised since it's not likely that the developer will always have control of the server response. Anyway, thanks for your help. Much appreciated.